# What are the differences between Restoration ID and identifier to a UITableViewCell that set in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, storyboard

When I drag a `UITableViewCell` to a tableView in `storyboard`, I find there are two ID to be set in the inspector. One is in the Identity Inspector(`Restoration ID`) and the other is in Attributes Inspector(identity).

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Restoration IDs are used for [state restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html), i.e. making your view look like it did when you quit the app-often used for *re-creating objects*. Storyboard IDs, on the other hand, simply identify objects on the storyboard-these are often used for *creating objects*.

Comment: It seems that I only need to set Restoration ID if I want to create cells with "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier", but I got nil...

Comment: No, in this case you want the Storyboard ID, since you're "creating" the cells.

Answer (score 15):

A **restoration identifier** is a string that you need to assign to any view controller or view that you want preserved and restored. During state preservation any view controllers or views in the view hierarchy that have a restoration identifier will be saved to disk.

The **Identity in the Identity Inspector**, are used to instantiate objects from Storyboard